# Adding random integer number in c++

Tags: c++, random

How do I add in c++ a random integer number between 100 and -100 to an int variable?

Comment: 1. Generate a random intereger
2. Add that integer
3. ????
4. PROFIT

Comment: How do I do step 1 i.e. generate a random integer? obviously adding it later is easy.

Comment: @lital maatuk - using `rand()` function. See the Nick's answer below.

Comment: @lital: If you know how to add two integers, then don't put it into your question. Seriously, it confuses people.

Comment: @Kiril: Alternatively, use [this](http://xkcd.com/221/).

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y - xD Yep, this one works, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int rnd = 0;
rnd += ( ( rand() * 200 ) / RAND_MAX ) - 100;
```

Edit: Obviously this is going to have issues where RAND_MAX is equal to INT_MAX. In which case the answer below: [Adding random integer number in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312294/adding-random-integer-number-in-c/5312413#5312413) is probably more appropriate.

Edit: On Windows platforms RAND_MAX is defined 0x7fff and so this calculation will succeed. On other platforms this may not be the case.

Comment: `RAND_MAX` is not guaranteed to be less than `INT_MAX`. In fact, on most systems it isn't.

Comment: Following up on @aaz comment : On my gcc/linux, `RAND_MAX == INT_MAX`. Since `rand()` returns an `int`, the expression `rand()*200` is of type `int`. So, the above expression has the bounds:  `( [0.INT_MAX]*200)/INT_MAX - 100)` or `([INT_MIN.INT_MAX]/INT_MAX - 100)`, or `(0 - 100)`.  This solution, on my machine, produces value `-100` regardless of the return value of `rand()`.

Comment: My heart aches when such seriously wrong answers are accepted by the OP.

Comment: @Nick: rand() * 200 will nearly always overflow if RAND_MAX is set to a sensible value. In the GNU C Library, for instance (http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_396.html), RAND_MAX is 2147483647. That's seriously wrong in my book!

Comment: But on Win32 RAND_MAX is defined as 0x7fff and so it's perfectly reasonable to use the calculation I provided on a windows platform.

Answer (score 5):

```
value += (rand() % 201) - 100; // it's 201 becouse with 200 the value would be in [-100, 99]
```

Don't forget to initialize the seed of random values (call srand()) or it will aways generate the same values. A good way to initialize the seed is with the time:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

**Generate a Random number between 0 to 100 and subtract it with a random number between 0 to 100.**

```
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <ctime> 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
srand((unsigned)time(0)); 
int random_integer; 
random_integer = (rand()%101) - (rand()%101); 
cout << random_integer << endl; 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will work, but it should be noted that the result will not be drawn from a uniform distribution. Look at `P(n=100)=P(a=100)*P(b=0) = 1/101 * 1/101 = 1/10201`, where n is the resultant number, a and b are the two numbers drawn. On the other hand `P(n=99)=P(a=99)*P(b=0) + P(a=100)*P(b=1) = 2/10201`. This trend continues right up to `P(n=0) = 1/101` and then symmetrically `P(n=-99) = 2/10201` and `P(n=-100) = 1/10201`.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11:

```
#include <random>

int main()
{
    typedef std::mt19937_64 G;
    G g;
    typedef std::uniform_int_distribution<> D;
    D d(-100, 100);
    int x = 0;
    x += d(g);
}
```

Other sources of randomness are also available, e.g:

```
minstd_rand0
minstd_rand
mt19937
ranlux24_base
ranlux48_base
ranlux24
ranlux48
knuth_b
```

Just change the typedef `G` to suit your taste.  And you can seed `g` at construction time as you like.